# Maintaining states of navigations in Material Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

`I am trying to create an application where I am using SingleActivity and rest fragments, The problem I am facing is that I am using  and <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView/> in my activity_main xml and in my MainActivity I have create navigation clicks. As I have 4 items in my bottom navigation I have assigned a navigation on every item click and it works

the solution I am looking for is
Suppose I have Fragment A , B , C and D as the 4 fragments I have alloted to itemclick

for instance I am on Fragment A and from there I navigate to Fragment A1 and then to Fragment A2
now I click on Fragment B from bottom navigation and My Fragment B appears
now when I click on Fragment A on bottomnavigation it should show A2 instead of A and that where I left my last navigation
and when I reselect the A again it clears the stack of navigations and Fragment A appears

P.S I am using navigation grapgh directions for moving A to A1 and to A2`

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentMain"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:stretchColumns="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:itemBackground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/theme"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Comment: as I understand, when you click an icon in a bottom bar you want to keep a fragment when you leave?

Comment: @HoàngVũAnh I am able to kind of achieve that by replacing fragments, The Fragments don't recreate. the issue is to preserve the last navigation state 

in simple words
I have 2 items in bottomNav,
Let's say home and profile
I navigate from home to Fragment A to A1
Home -> Fragment A -> Fragment A1
I click on Profile
I click on home again from bottomNav
it should show me A1 instead of home without recreating anything

Comment: Please create a new Android project and see the result, it's the same as you want